# How to create a mysql union of tables by using another table in the same database to select

Tags: php, mysql, database, union

I have a search function on my website that combines all of the tables using the UNION function and everything works fine except for the fact that it is a static statement. Currently it looks like the code below. I have another table in the database called conferencelist that has the names of all of the conferences. In the future I might want to add more conferences to the conferencelist table, but I don't want to have to go into the code below and add the table. Is there a way to pull the data from the conferencelist table and insert it into the SELECT * FROM conference.

```html
<?php
if($search_type == "Last Name"){
    $raw_results_query = "(SELECT * FROM AtlanticCoastConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM CoastalCollegiateSwimmingAssociation
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NCAADivisionII
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NCAADivisionI
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM PacificCollegiateConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM PAC12
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM BIG12
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM BigEast
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM MountainWest
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM ColonialAthleticConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM LittleEastConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM GreaterNewEnglandConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NEWMAC
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NESCAC
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM Atlantic10Conference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM ConferenceUSA
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM MetroAtlanticAthleticConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM Northeast10Conference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM MissouriValleyConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM MAC
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM MetroConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM MichiganIntercollegiateAthleticAssociation
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NorthernSunConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM Empire8Conference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NorthCentralConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM PatriotLeague
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM CoastalAthleticSwimAssociation
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM UniversityAthleticAssociation
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NorthCoastAthleticConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM SunbeltConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM MissouriValleyConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NorthCoastConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM SUNYACConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM NCAADivisionIII
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM BIG10
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM SoutheasternConference
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))
            UNION
            (SELECT * FROM USADiving
            WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%'))";
}
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't work... what I altimatley want is a loop that will make a UNION of all of the conferences from the conferencelist table.

```html
<?php 
$result1=mysqli_query($con,"select * From conferenceList ORDER By id ASC");
echo "$raw_results_query = '";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "(SELECT * FROM ";
    echo "$row[name]";
    echo "WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%".$query."%')) UNION";
}
echo "';";
                
?>
```

Comment: I think your database has an extremly bad design - Seems you need only 1 table which has an identifier column. - What are you trying to achieve? I'm sure you could have a much easier life by having only 1 table

Comment: @B001ᛦ the lname is only the value searched... the different tables all have different values along with lname... im trying to create a search function that will be able to search all of the tables along with newly created tables in the future

Comment: _...different tables all have different values ..._ Do they have different structure? Different columns? I don't mean their value

Comment: @B001ᛦ yes they all have the same structure... I see your point, but if I combine all of the tables there will be over 2000 rows. If I do combine the tables... is there a way to combine them all in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Databases are designed to hold millions of rows. 2000 rows should not be a problem.

Comment: 2000? Are you kidding me? merge all tables into 1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just echoing all the subqueries, put them into an array, join the array with `UNION` between them, and use that to create the big query.

```
$queries = [];
$result1=mysqli_query($con,"select name From conferenceList");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $queries[] = "(SELECT * FROM $row[name] WHERE (`lname` LIKE '%$query%'))";
}
$raw_results_query = implode(' UNION ', $queries);
```

Make sure you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` when setting `$query`. Ideally you would use a prepared statement, but that's hard to do in mysqli with a dynamic number of parameters (this is one of the many reasons I prefer PDO).